# Show that a (particular) continuous, one-to-one mapping is also surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove a topological fact, but the question comes from a graph theory text, "Combinatorial Geometry" (J, Pach and P.K. Agarwal). So, it's hard to say exactly what topology I am supposed to know to answer the question. I can however give my thoughts on the problem so far.

The Question:

> Let $f$ be a continuous one-to-one mapping from the interior of the $d$-dimensional ball $B^d$ $(d\geq 1)$ to itself. Prove that if all accumulation points of $f(p)$, as $p$ tends to some boundary point of $B^d$, lie on $\partial B^d$, then $f(B^d)=B^d$.

Here is my attempt:
I first extend $f$ to the map $f':\overline{B^d}\rightarrow \overline{B^d}$ by defining $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}f(x),& x\in B^d,\\ \lim_{s\rightarrow x}f(s), & x\in \partial B^d. \end{cases}$$
I show $f'$ is defined and continuous. Then $f'$ is closed since $\overline{B^d}$ is Hausdorff and compact. Since $f$ is relatively closed and one-to-one, I argue that $f$ is actually a topological embedding.

Now I proceed by contradiction, and suppose that $B^d\backslash f(B^d)$ is non-empty. From here I argue that $f(B^d)$ must contain a boundary point in the interior of $B^d$. And once I've shown this I feel really close. I just need to show that the topological embedding $f$ cannot send $B^d$ to a subset of $B^d$ that contains some topological boundary. But although I find this believable, I'm not sure how to show it.

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I might just be lacking the topological knowledge to complete the argument, I don't know what the text expects me to know topology wise.

Comment: Do you know that $\partial B^d$ is (1) topologically characterised as the set of points in $B^d$ that have a neighbourhood homeomorphic to a half-space of $\Bbb{R}^d$ and (2) that $\partial B^d$ is not homeomorphic to any subset of itself. (1) is fairly easy to prove. (2) requires some homology theory. There may be a proof that avoids the homology theory, but I can't think of one.

Comment: Why would $\lim_{s\to x}f(x)$ exist?

Comment: @RobArthan As far as (1) goes, it's clear to me that each boundary point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to a half space of $R^d$. But I don't know how to show that interior points would lack this property, which I think is what (1) is getting at. I haven't studied homology so (2) is unknown to me. I don't know what the text expects as prior knowledge, if homology is required to answer the question then it seems I'm out of luck as far as proving it for myself.

Comment: @Berci I should probably explicitly restrict my approach of the limit to $s$ contained in $B^d$ . But I thought the assumption that ''all accumulation points of $f(p)$, as $p$ tends to some boundary point of $B^d$, lie on $\partial B^d$'', along with the continuity of $f$, would be enough to show existence of such a limit.

Comment: @Berci's comment on your interpretation is right: with $d = 2$, take the open square region $S$ with vertices at $(0,0, (0, 1), (1, 1)$ and $(0, 1)$ and the open triangular region $T$ with vertices at $(0, 0), (1, 1)$ and $(0, 1)$. Then $(x, y) \mapsto (x/y, y)$ gives a homeomorphism from $T$ to $S$. Identifying both $S$ and $T$ with $B^2$ gives a homeomorphism $f: B^2 \to B^2$  for which your definition of $f'$ doesn't work, while the hypotheses of the problem hold. (If $p_n \to (0, 0)$ in $T$, $f(p_n)$ *will*  have all its accumulation points in $\partial B^2$, but may not converge.)

Comment: ... I'm now thinking about the original problem. I still don't see any way of approaching it that doesn't require some facts from algebraic topology, specifically [invariance of domain[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) or some related result.

Comment: @RobArthan That's a great example for the non-existence of the limit, thank you. And thanks.  Also thanks for the reference for the Invariance of Domain. It seems to capture this problem very well.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for pointing out my mistake! I really underestimated the subtlety of multivariable limits here.